# Read.Table - Having problems with percentage character

Tags: r, read.table, csv

I am trying to read in a tab-separated file (available online, using ftp) using read.table() in R.

The issue seems to be that for the third column, the character string for some of the rows contains characters such as apostrophe character *'*  as well as percentage character *%* for example *Capital gains 15.0%* and *Bob's earnings*, for example -

*810| 13  | Capital gains 15.0% |* 
*170| -20 | Bob’s earnings|*
*100| 80  | Income|*

To handle the apostrophe character, I was using the following syntax
`df <- read.table(url('ftp://location'), sep="|", quote="\"", as.is=T)`

Yet this syntax shown above does not seem to handle the lines where the problematic third column contains a string with the percentage character, so that the entire remainder of the table is jammed into one field by the function.

I also tried to ignore the third column altogether by using colClasses  `df <- read.table(url('ftp://location'), sep="|", quote="\"", as.is=T, colClasses=c("numeric", "numeric", "NULL"))`, but the function still fails over on the lines with the percentage character is present in that third column.

Any ideas on how to address the issue?

Comment: Can you post an example line or two from the file? Can you recreate the problem with a smaller sample file?

Comment: Please don't try to post the sample lines in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: You could try `df<-readLines('ftp://location')` to read in the data as it is and clean up later i.e., `df<-gsub("%","pct",df)` and `df<-do.call(rbind,strsplit(df,"|"))` for delimited data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of read.table wrapper, use scan function. You can control anything. And is faster, specially if you use "what" option to indicate R what are you scanning.

```
dat <- scan(file     = "data.tsv",                            # Substitute this for url
        what     = list(c(rep("numeric",2), "character")),    # describe columns 
        skip     =  0,                                        # lines to skip
        sep      = "|")                                       # separator
```

Instead of file, use your url.
In this case scan is expecting 2 columns of "numeric" followed by a column of "character"

Type

```
?scan
```

to get the complete list of options.